# binarized jason which looks good on browsers

Tags: json, browser

I'm looking into an HTTP interface that returns (essentially) a JSON object.

When I access the URL by chrome or firefox, the JSON data is shown with appropriate indents. However, when I download it with curl etc, the data is binary.

I think the browsers know this binary encoding method and show it in a pretty format. (If I save it as a file from the browsers, it is a text file with the indents.)

What do you think this binary encoding is? 
(Unfortunately, I can not upload the binary data here...)

---

[SOLVED]
Browsers send requests with headers but curl doesn't send header by default. That is the reason why I get the different response by these methods. My API returns binarized (compressed) json when called without a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look in the header of the HTTP response message which contains the binary data. There should be values about encoding, content-type and compression. 
With this values you can decode the binary data.

Comment: press F12 in your browser. Depending on your browser you should have a tab "network". After opening this you have to execute your request again. Then you should see the response. With a double click you can see the details of the request and response messages.

Comment: Connection: keep-alive, Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

Comment: In the request headars, Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Comment: I found the approach looking into the header is good. Thank you!